# How should `flow offload` statements be configured when using flowtables?

Tags: networking, firewall, nftables

[**Flowtables**](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Flowtables) is an `nftables` feature for offloading traffic to a "fast path" that skips the typical forwarding path once a connection is established. Two things need to be configured to set up flowtables. First is the `flowtable` itself, which is defined as part of a table. Second is a `flow offload` statement, and this is what my question is about. The `nft` man page says:

```
FLOW STATEMENT
    A flow statement allows us to select what flows you want to accelerate
    forwarding through layer 3 network stack bypass. You have to specify
    the flowtable name where you want to offload this flow.

    flow add @flowtable
```

The [wiki page](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Flowtables) includes this full configuration example:

```
table inet x {

    flowtable f {
        hook ingress priority 0; devices = { eth0, eth1 };
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

        # offload established connections
        ip protocol { tcp, udp } flow offload @f
        ip6 nexthdr { tcp, udp } flow offload @f
        counter packets 0 bytes 0

        # established/related connections
        ct state established,related counter accept

        # allow initial connection
        ip protocol { tcp, udp } accept
        ip6 nexthdr { tcp, udp } accept
    }
}
```

Here's where I get confused. The example uses the same condition (`ip protocol { tcp, udp }`) to both `accept` the traffic and to `flow offload` it. Is that because `flow offload` will implicitly `accept` a flow by adding it to the flowtable, meaning those conditions should always match? Or is it just a coincidence in this example, and the `accept` rule could be more restrictive?

Concretely, suppose I only want to forward SSH traffic inbound from `eth0`, and I want to enable flow offloading. Should I configure the forward chain like this?

```
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

        # offload established connections
        ip protocol { tcp, udp } flow offload @f

        # established/related connections
        ct state established,related counter accept

        # allow initial connection
        iif eth0 tcp dport 22 accept
    }
```

Or like this? (only the `flow offload` rule has changed)

```
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;

        # offload established connections
        iif eth0 tcp dport 22 flow offload @f

        # established/related connections
        ct state established,related counter accept

        # allow initial connection
        iif eth0 tcp dport 22 accept
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few key sentences that I first want to point out from the wiki:

> You can select which flows you want to offload through the flow
> expression from the forward chain.

> Flows are offloaded after the state is created. That means that
> usually the first reply packet will create the flowtable entry. A
> firewall rule to accept the initial traffic is required. The flow
> expression on the forward chain must match the return traffic of the
> initial connection.

Getting even more specific, it points out:

> This also means if you are using special ip rules, you need to make
> sure that they match the reply packet traffic as well as the original
> traffic.

I found in my experiences with it, working out reply direction, estab or not, initial etc was just too hard.

Also from their example, pay close attention to their comments; the flow statement offloads established, and further down you must accept the initial connection(s).

Offloading in general is a good thing IMO, so I just use a broad flow statement like this:

```
ip6 nexthdr { tcp, udp } flow add @f counter
ip protocol { tcp, udp } flow add @f counter
```

And then I allow out and in as normal:

```
ct state established,related counter accept
iif $DEV_INSIDE counter accept
iif $DEV_OUTSIDE ip6 daddr <mail server> tcp dport { smtp } counter accept
```

The flow statement definitely does not just accept everything, although it looks that way.  Look at their ASCII diagram above and it should make more sense.

Pablo Neira Ayuso put it a [slightly different way](https://lwn.net/Articles/738214/):

> The 'flow offload' action adds the flow entry once the flow is in
> established state, according to the connection tracking definition, ie.
> we have seen traffic in both directions. Therefore, only initial packets
> of the flow follow the classic forwarding path.

So in summary, yes, you could get more specific in the `flow add` statements, but why bother when ultimately, flows follow ESTAB state, and you can maintain protection with normal, stateful rules elsewhere.

[This resource](https://thermalcircle.de/doku.php?id=blog:linux:flowtables_1_a_netfilter_nftables_fastpath) is also quite in-depth and awesome.

I would go with your first example, and just double-check with an `nmap` scan.  Also note that you can then check for success using `conntrack -L`.